# Can GeoCoder getFromLocation method cause a NetworkOnMainThreadException to be thrown?

Tags: android, android-maps, android-networking, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an app which was tested thoroughly and working fine on Android Gingerbread (and older Android versions). I've noticed from users' reported crash errors that phones running later versions of the Android operating system are throwing a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

I'm trying to work through my code and eliminate/fix all culprits. Would the `GeoCoder` `getFromLocation` and `getFromLocationName` methods throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` if called from the main/ui thread?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like these `Geocoder` methods and ***any*** networking or i/o calls are going to throw up a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. So, if in doubt, stick it in a separate thread!

Here's an example of how to call the `GeoCoder.getFromLocation()` method from another thread:

```
new AsyncTask<GeoPoint, Void, Address>()
{
  @Override
  protected Address doInBackground(GeoPoint... geoPoints)
  {
    try
    {
      Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context);
      double latitude = geoPoints[0].getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
      double longitude = geoPoints[0].getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
      List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
      if (addresses.size() > 0)
        return addresses.get(0);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      // log exception or do whatever you want to do with it!
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Address address)
  {
    // do whatever you want/need to do with the address found
    // remember to check first that it's not null
  }
}.execute(myGeoPoint);
```