# Map activity crashes after search a place with autocomplete

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Hi Im new in android maps, I have a maps activity that add markers when I search an address with autocomplete, everything works fine when search address(street,state,country), the issue is that when I search by place like Mcdonalds or a specific building the autocomplete works fine, but when it should add the markers the activity crashes. I already have Google maps api key and Google places server key

add marker code below

thanks in advance!

```
 Intent o = getIntent();
    String textOrigin = o.getStringExtra("TextBoxOrigin");


List<Address> addressListOrigin=null;



    if(textOrigin !=null)
    {
        Geocoder geocoderOrigin=new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressListOrigin=geocoderOrigin.getFromLocationName(textOrigin,1);


        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Check if origin exist
        if(addressListOrigin != null && addressListOrigin.size() > 0) {

            Address addressOrigin = addressListOrigin.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(addressOrigin.getLatitude(), addressOrigin.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("your position").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.worker_pin2)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate1 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12);
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate1);
        }else{
            noLocationFound();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geocoder's getFromLocationName() method must run on a separate thread from the UI, check out the answer here:

[Can GeoCoder getFromLocation method cause a NetworkOnMainThreadException to be thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893520/can-geocoder-getfromlocation-method-cause-a-networkonmainthreadexception-to-be-t)